# Pitch detection from FFT in C#

Tags: c#, fft, pitch

I'm making a programm to tune brass band. I'm starting recording from mic.

```
public void StartMicListening()
    {
        int audioDevNumber = 0;
        WaveInEvent wIN = new WaveInEvent();
        wIN.DeviceNumber = audioDevNumber;
        wIN.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(RATE, 1);
        wIN.BufferMilliseconds = (int)((double)BUFFERSIZE / (double)RATE * 1000.0);
        wIN.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(AudioDataAvailable);
        bwp = new BufferedWaveProvider(wIN.WaveFormat);
        bwp.BufferLength = BUFFERSIZE * 2;
        bwp.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
        try
        {
            wIN.StartRecording();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can't see device");
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("Recording");
    }
```

next I'm calculate FFT

```
public void calculateFFT()
    {
        var audioBytes = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
        bwp.Read(audioBytes, 0, BUFFERSIZE);
        int pointCount = audioBytes.Length / 2;
        double[] pcm = new double[pointCount];
        double[] fft = new double[pointCount];
        double[] fftReal = new double[pointCount/2];


        for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
        {
            // read the int16 from the two bytes
            Int16 val = BitConverter.ToInt16(audioBytes, i * 2);

            // store the value in Ys as a percent (+/- 100% = 200%)
            pcm[i] = (double)(val) / Math.Pow(2, 18) * 200.0;
        }
        fft = FFT(pcm);
        Array.Copy(fft, fftReal, fftReal.Length);

    }
```

When I'm testing this code with tone generator (https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/) with 440 Hz tone , and I get max value from fftReal it's working good. But when I using it with saxophone sound and I get max value from fftReal I detect sometimes 440Hz, sometimes 880 Hz, sometimes 1320 Hz. 880 Hz and 1320 Hz are aliquot of A tone (440 Hz), but I have to detect only first pitch of spectrum (440 Hz). Is there any solution of this? Mayba some of you have already done it in C# and can share me it.

Comment: Pitch detection is much more complicated that just finding the frequency of the fundamental or largest peak in a complex sound. Pitch and frequency are not the same thing! You might want to do some reading on the subject before you write any more code. As well as searching Stack Overflow and Google for "pitch detection" you might also want to search for "Harmonic Product Spectrum", which is a popular algorithm for pitch detection for musical instruments etc.

Comment: You could probably use a library to do this for you, something like [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) might work for example